# Email via Google Cloud Functions trigger erratic syntax error

Tags: google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

I was trying out a google cloud function to send an email after these examples:
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users
and https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sendgrid-v3-nodejs-transactional-email-cloud-function/
Then I had to make some adjustments to fit the developing technologies and my result is this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
const sendGrid = require('@sendgrid/mail');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();
const SENDGRID_API_KEY="***";
sgMail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY);
sendGrid.setApiKey(functions.config().sendgrid.apikey);
sendGrid.setSubstitutionWrappers('{{', '}}');
exports.httpEmail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
cors( req, res, () => { 

const name  = req.body.toName;
const email = req.body.Email;
const id = req.body.ID;

const msg = {
    to: email,
    from: mail@homepage.com',
    subject: id,
    text: `Hello {{name}}`,
    html: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`
};

return sgMail.send(msg)

    .then(() => res.status(200).send('email sent!') )
    .catch(err => res.status(400).send(err) )

});});
```

Now this gives me a syntax error

> /user_code/index.js:20 to: {{email}}, ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token

```
{
  "name": "email",
  "description": "sending emails",
  "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": {
    "sendgrid/mail": "^6.3.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.1",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.11.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint --max-warnings=0 .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

And this gives me a parse error:

> Cannot parse package.json, error at line 7 column 6

Both errors do not make sense to me and I had to make 4 different adjustments which leaves me in doubt that I am on my right way at all. Anyone got a working example or tutorial including cors, text with variables and sendgrid? Or could someone solve the error message for me?

Answer (score 0):

1. first error is due to the absence of the opening quote in `mail@homepage'`
2. second maybe to the absence of '@' before `sendgrid/mail`, or no indentation under `"dependencies"`

While `sendgrid` is a good option, you might also look at [`nodemailer`](https://nodemailer.com/about/). It doesn't require an API key. Both methods work the same, shown in below example.

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: nodejs8
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemailer": "^4.0.1",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^6.3.1"
  }
}
```

**app.js**

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const sendgridmail = require('@sendgrid/mail');

exports.sendEmail = (req, res) => {

  // destination email passed as argument
  var email = req.query.message;

  // sender email config (mailserver)
  var gmailEmail = process.env.EMAIL;
  var gmailPassword = process.env.PASSWORD;


  // Nodemailer config
  var mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
      user: gmailEmail,
      pass: gmailPassword
    }
  });

  var msg = {
    from: gmailEmail,
    to: email,
    subject: 'Nodemailer',
    text: 'Sent with Nodemailer'
  };

  mailTransport.sendMail(msg);

  // Sendgrid config
  sendgridmail.setApiKey(process.env.GRIDKEY);

  var msg = {
    from: gmailEmail,
    to: email,
    subject: 'Sendgrid',
    text: 'Sent with Sendgrid/mail'
  };

  sendgridmail.send(msg);

  return `Sent two emails with Sendgrid and Nodemailer`;
};
```

**Nb.** as I am using Gmail as mail server, two additional steps were required to be able to send emails from it:

1. [Allow Less Secure Apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)
2. [Allow access to your Google account](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)